# FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#

I'm trying to use F# for an ASP.NET MVC application. One my controller actions sends an F# list to the view, so I write:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="ViewPage<FSharpList<int>>" %>
```

Of course, for this to work, I have to add `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections` to the [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx) element in my web.config:

```
<add namespace="Microsoft.FSharp.Collections"/>
```

and add a reference to `FSharp.Core`, in the [assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfyb45k1.aspx) element:

```
<add assembly="FSharp.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

As soon as I add this assembly reference, every view (whether it uses an F# type or not) fails with this error:

> error FS1221: FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core

I can work around this by not having any F# specific types in my views, but what's the reason for this error? Also, where's `FSharp.Core.sigdata` ? It's not in my GAC and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Could you upload your current project somewhere? I'd be happy to try it, but it would be useful to have some project to start with :-).

Comment: @Tomas: thanks, I'll try to create a small project that reproduces this.

Comment: @Tomas: here's the project: http://www.box.net/shared/7xnkfg5yps

Comment: I have a similar problem. However it's temporary. on my CI server one build works fine the other fails when looking for sigdata. They use the exact same build script. The only dif between them is what happens afterwards when there's no ubild errors

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll find it with the Reference Assemblies, as sigdata and optdata are design-time things (but I guess CodeDom needs them too?), e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.dll
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.optdata
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v2.0\FSharp.Core.sigdata
```

If you copy those next to the FSharp.Core that the app is using, it will probably work.

Comment: Tried copying both optdata and sigdata to my app's bin, same error. I also tried copying them to the FSharp.Core's directory in the GAC, same thing.

Comment: Was resolved for me after copying optdata and sigdata alongside FSharp.Core.dll.

Comment: @tovyo: for a web application?

Comment: Copying opdata and sigdata alongside FSharp.Core.dll in the deployment folder worked for me in a .Net 4.5 console application

Comment: this actually helped, added FSharp.Core.optdata and FSharp.Core.sigdata to the project as content and set the properties to CopyAlways and it fixed the problem.