# F# Compilation Error on Windows 8.1 Pro VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#, f#-3.0, windows-8.1

I am very new to F# and F# on visual studio.
I just created a F# application and created a class, when I try with F# interactive window it works fine, When I build the application it gives fallowing three errors

```
FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core FSC

Error opening binary file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\v4.0_4.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll': FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core

Problem reading assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a': Error opening binary file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\v4.0_4.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll': FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core
```

Please advice me how it can be sorted.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733415/fsharp-core-sigdata-not-found-alongside-fsharp-core ? I'm going to guess it has something to do with Windows 8.1

Comment: Yes I have seen that post. But I didn't install F# 2.0 and I am trying on F# 3.0 also I can not find any stand alone installer for F# 3.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2012 to work properly in Windows 8.1 you have to install VS2012 Update 3 after upgrading to Windows 8.1.

Comment: If you installed Update 3 before Windows 8.1, run the Update 3 installer and click Repair.